# Defining a custom placeholder variable of type Double in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nan

Is it possible to define a custom placeholder variable of type Double in Matlab, with its properties being similar to the inbuilt NaN or Inf? Lets call the desired placeholder variable as PhV, which should have the following properties:

1. Algebra of PhV: PhV (+) expr = PhV, where 'expr' is an element of type Double or a PhV itself, and the binary operation '(+)' can be one of the algebraic operations in the set {+,-,*,/,^}
2. Type of PhV: it should be of type Double

For example NaN satisfies both the properties mentioned above, and we can use NaN in a double array. Also when using fprintf for NaN, we can use the numeric format specifiers (%d or %e) and it appears as NaN in the output.
I am using Matlab2006b on a 64 bit GNU/Linux, though I would like to know if there is a way we can do it in Matlab, in general.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So, why not just use `NaN`?

Comment: I have no experience with object oriented programming in matlab, but I think that's basically what you will have to look into if you want to implement something which satisfies your specifications to an acceptable degree.

Comment: @LuisMendo: I do not want to use NaN for such variables because they are not actually NaN's. In my case, out of N variables in a problem, I find that n(<N) variables do not affect the problem and I may not solve for them, hence I want to assign them a special value, signifying this. Also the algebra defined above will make sure that any expression which uses such variables will get PhV as well.
Also I am aware that I can keep track of such variables and do some post-processing to report them as I want, but I would prefer implementing a generic solution for this purpose.

Comment: @timgeb: thanks, I will explore on the suggested approach.